# Is there a has_more_tag() method or equivalent?

Tags: theme-development, read-more

I need to determine if the current post has a "more" tag. I'm currently using

```
$pos=strpos($post->post_content, '<!--more-->');
```

Am I missing a built in method similar to has_excerpt()?

Comment: Not sure exactly where you're trying to run your code, but if you're on a single post view the `$pages` global should hold a value representing the number of pages(if the post is paged, ie. has content that spans pages, eg. it has more!)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply put: there is no built in function that does the same thing as your code above.

Bonus content: [More tag tricks](http://digwp.com/2010/01/wordpress-more-tag-tricks/)

Answer (score 9):

Making a quick note of the codes we could use to show `the_content();` if the More tag exists, and `the_excerpt();` if it doesn't.

### Code #1 (Recommended)

```
<?php
    if( strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
        the_content();
    }
    else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```

(**Credit:** [MichaelH](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/270651?replies=3#post-1074226))

### Code #2

```
<?php
    if( strpos( get_the_content(), 'more-link' ) === false ) {
        the_excerpt();
    }
    else {
        the_content();
    }
?>
```

(**Credit:** [Michael](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4884/michael)) Basically does **#1** the other way around.

### Code #3

```
<?php
    if( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post->post_content ) ) {
        the_content();
    }
    else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```

(**Credit:** [helgatheviking](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/6477/helgatheviking)) For use only in edge cases where you cannot use `strpos()`. Generally `strpos()` is more efficient than `preg_match()`.

---

Making it more conditional:

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {
        if( strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) );
        }
        else {
            the_excerpt();
        }
    }
    else {
        the_content();
    }
?>
```

**What does it do?** If the page shown is home, archive or search results page, then show `the_content();` if the More tag exists, `the_excerpt();` if it doesn't, and simply show `the_excerpt();` on all other pages.

Comment: The idea of posting this answer here was to get all the codes in one place. :)

Comment: Don't count on `get_the_content()` to return `more-link` in all cases (I got a span with an id of `more-214` for example). Use `$post->post_content` and look for `<!--more-->` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not get any of the provided solution to work, however I found this to be working well for me, publishing it as an extra solution if anybody else had problems getting it working. Just testing if the content is them same with and without stripping the teaser.

```
        // Choose the manual excerpt if exists
        if ( has_excerpt() ) :
                the_excerpt();

        // Is there a more tag? Then use the teaser. ()
        elseif ( get_the_content('', false) != get_the_content('', true)  ) :
            global $more; 
            $more = 0;
            echo strip_tags(get_the_content( '', false ));
            $more = 1;

        // Otherwise make an automatic excerpt
        else :
            the_excerpt(40);

        endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones searching for a more WP related answer, You can use this logic:

```
$info = get_extended($post->post_content);
if(!empty($info["extended"])){
   // it has a read more tag.
}else{
   // it hasn't one.
}
```

For this, you can blame the WP Core if it doesn't work right. :)

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_extended/